# Wii Mario Kart World Records Contaminated for the Ghost Time Trials?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

Is it just me or I see the Toad's Factory, Coconut Mall, DK Summit with World Records being ridiculously low in time and viewing the Replay, it went on and on and the karts or bikes are just crashing into fences for 10 minutes or more.

Is their site being hacked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the **site** is not being hacked, but the players who are 'achieving' these times are cheating/hacking.  It's sad, but there's nothing we can really do about it.  :(

Comment: How do they cheat ?

Comment: no, they are not using glitch to run the whole race for 30 seconds... the time displayed is 00:00.016  so it is not even 1 second, and then, when you see the replay, they just sit idle.  That's not cheating the course, that's hacking.

Comment: Hacking is cheating.  :)

Comment: how do they do it?

Comment: I'm not an expert on hacking my Wii, so I really have no idea.